# XSLT: remove duplicate br-tags from running text

Tags: xml, xslt

When editing rich text content, our CMS generates XML-files with duplicate `<br/>`-tags. I'd like to remove them in order to generate output that can be read by another application that does not appreciate the occurrence of those duplicates.

Example input:

```
<p>
   Lorem ipsum...<br />
   <br />
   ..dolor sit
</p>
```

Would generate something like this:

```
<p>
   Lorem ipsum...<br />
   ..dolor sit
</p>
```

I am already using XSLT to manipulate the output in some other ways, and have found some examples of regexps and PHP that does the same thing, I just think it would be better if I could do this with XSLT due to the speed of the engine in our CMS (Roxen).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good question... a trickier problem than it seems at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building off @Nic's answer, you could use

```
<xsl:template match='br[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::br]]'/>
```

I've just changed `*` to `node()`.
This would solve the problem of conflating two `<br/>`s that have text in between. However it would stop removing duplicate `<br/>`s even if there is only a whitespace node in between.

To solve that...

**Deprecated**

At first I had suggested you could strip whitespace-only nodes from `p` elements in the input doc, by putting this at the top level of your XSLT:

```
<xsl:strip-space  elements="p"/>
```

But @Alejandro pointed out that **this could easily cause you to lose important spaces**, as in `<p><em>bar</em> <em>baz</em></p>`.

**So instead,**

use this modified match pattern:

```
<xsl:template match='br[preceding-sibling::node()
                        [not(self::text() and normalize-space(.) = "")][1]
                        [self::br]]'/>
```

Kind of ugly but it should work.
This will match and suppress "any br for which the preceding sibling node that is not a whitespace-only text node is also a br." :-)

Given that the match pattern is so complex, you may prefer to move some of that logic into the template body, as follows. I guess this is more a matter of personal taste and style:

```
<xsl:template match="br">
   <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::node()
                        [not(self::text() and normalize-space(.) = '')][1]
                        [self::br])">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Here we use a copy of the identity transform when the `<br />` is not one we want to suppress. I don't think `<br />` can take child elements or text, but it doesn't hurt to be safe.

(**Updated the above.** I had forgotten to finish that sample code last time I saved edits.)

Comment: @dotmartin, I updated my answer to give a better indication of how to solve this more elegantly and efficiently, using `xsl:strip-space`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this @LarsH. We are using the output for internal purposes (i.e. the xml is imported in InDesign to create a printed copy from the news in the CMS), this does the trick of washing the duplicate `<br/>`'s. Transforming XML using XSLT is interesting business, I really like the flexibility it gives in presenting information in many different ways. However, thanks for your help @LarsH & @Nic

Comment: I think that needs a slight modification still - aren't you currently testing against the first preceding non-whitespace text node and not the first preceding node if it is not a whitespace text node? I think you need to put the `[1]` before the rest of the predicates.

Comment: @LarsH and @Nic Gibson: LarsH modifications are correct. I would use a pattern like `'br[preceding-sibling::node()[not(self::text()[not(normalize-space())][1]/self::br]`. About `xsl:strip-space`: because this is XHTML/HTML, I don't think this is the solution. Also +1.

Comment: @Nic: thanks for your comment... I looked at it again and I'm pretty sure the way it is is correct... The intent is to skip over whitespace-only text nodes and consider the next node beyond them; if we put the [1] right after node(), we wouldn't be able to skip anything. The [not(self::text() and ...)] should yield true for non-text nodes, so I should be testing against the first preceding non-whitespace text node. Gotta go to breakfast now... will think more about it later.

Comment: @Alej, thanks for your comment. Can you elaborate more about why xsl:strip-space wouldn't work because the input is XHTML/HTML?

Comment: @Alejandro - I am actually transforming XML. The output is an XML-file not used by a browser (besides providing a link to download it). Could you give me some more details on why to not use the `xsl:strip-space`, are there any risks etcetera of doing this?

Comment: @LarsH: That's because white space only text nodes are meaningful in XHTML/HTML for both "block" elements and "inline" elements: i.e. `<p>This <b>is</b> <i>posible</i>. Don't you think so?</p>`

Comment: @LarsH: Good and detailed answer, +1.

Comment: Also, my pattern has a typo. It should be: `br[preceding-sibling::node()[not(self::text()[not(normalize-space())]][1]/self::br]`

Comment: @LarsH - yeah I went and tried it. You're absolutely right. Wasn't paying enough attention.

Comment: @Alej, good point about not wanting to strip whitespace-only nodes in mixed content! I guess that's why whitespace-only nodes are not stripped by default in XSLT. @dotmartin, I'm going to edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Using an identity transform to leave everything else alone, you could simply suppress every `<br/>` that is directly preceded by another one. Obviously, you can then just fit the template into your existing XSLT.

```
<xsl:template match='node()|@*'>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='node()|@*'/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='br[(preceding-sibling::*)[1][self::br]]'/>
```

The empty template will simply suppress that `<br/>`.

Update:
As @LarsH points out, that template is too liberal in its matching and probably should be something like:

```
<xsl:template match='br[preceding-sibling::node()[1]
    [not(self::text() and normalize-space(.) = "")][self::br]]'/>
```

Comment: Yeah! Exactly what I was looking for. Great stuff! I always seem to fail to remember the greatness of actually supressing stuff using XSLT. :) Thanks a billion!

Comment: @Nic: nice; however this suppresses every `<br/>` for which the preceding *sibling element* is another `<br/>`, regardless of intervening text. It would change `<p>Foo<br /><br />bar<br /><br />baz</p>` to `<p>Foo<br />barbaz</p>`, eliminating *both* br's between bar and baz. Right? Now that structure may not occur in the input, I don't know.

Comment: @LarsH I kind of made the assumption that there weren't any given the input and the OP's description. You are right though. Without seeing the entire document I can't make the assumption but checking for non whitespace text nodes might be wise too.

Comment: @Nic, it seems like a dubious assumption... if a `<p>` can have one (double) line break in it, surely some of them will have two or more, with text in between.

Comment: @LarsH Yes that's correct, the document might have more than one pair of `<br/>`. The correct output from the comment above should be `<p>Foo<br />bar<br />baz`.

Comment: @dotmartin - it's not really the pairs that are the worry - my code would have stripped something like `<p>foo<br/>bar</br></p>` to <p>foo<br/>bar</p>`.

Comment: @Nic - Yes, I noticed this result when testing some different input.

Comment: @Alejandro - yeah, wasn't paying enough attention. LarsH has the right answer :)

Comment: @Nic Gibson: Not big deal. Your answer is almost right and it has the right approuch. It would be the right answer in any other case where white space only text nodes were not important.