# Remove exceeding more than n consecutive br-tags from running text

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have some rich text input and want to allow only a maximum of two consecutive `<br>` tags.

I found a partial good answer to my problem: [XSLT: remove duplicate br-tags from running text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085717/xslt-remove-duplicate-br-tags-from-running-text)

However I need to allow up to two consecutive `<br>` tags. A more general question would be: how to allow a maximum of n consecutive `<br>` tags?

Example input:

```html
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum...<br>
        <br>
        <br>

        ..dolor sit
    </p>
```

Needed output:

```html
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum...<br>
        <br>

        ..dolor sit
    </p>
```

Example input 2:

```html
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum...<br>
        lorem ... <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        ..dolor sit
    </p>
```

Needed output:

```html
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum...<br>
        lorem ... <br>
        <br>

        ..dolor sit
    </p>
```

Comment: I will add that the library I use for XSLT, Nokogiri, seems to support only XSLT 1.0 and XPath 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you have XHTML, so `<br/>` instead of `<br>`! And then:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
    <!-- Catch-all templates -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- specific part -->
    <xsl:template match="br">
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::node()[local-name() or normalize-space()][1][local-name()='br']) or not(preceding-sibling::node()[local-name() or normalize-space()][2][local-name()='br'])">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Depending on how many `<br>`'s following each other directly you want to allow, you can add more of the same, e.g. for the third one: `or not(preceding-sibling::node()[local-name() or normalize-space()][3][local-name()='br'])`, 4th one `or not(preceding-sibling::node()[local-name() or normalize-space()][4][local-name()='br'])` etc.

Comment: No, Joel's solution doesn't work. In your input xml sample, try adding some text or any xml element between the first and the second `<br>`, then you will see that this does not perform your expected behavior. So **if** you want a shorter solution that works, then accept GomX's approach!

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="br">
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::node()
            [not(self::text() and normalize-space(.) = '')][2]
            [self::br])">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there's text or other elements between the `<br>`'s.

Comment: @Kimmy The OP expressly asks about "consecutive" `br` elements which I think means _adjacent_ consecutive elements. Elements between `br` elements are not an issue in my opinion.

Comment: I agree they shouldn't be an issue, but they *are* in your xsl. Try it!

Comment: The problem at hand is removing consecutive br elements. If there is text in between, there can be any number of br elements in my case. This version removes too many br elements

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in your stylesheet:

```
   <!-- set desired threshold here -->
   <xsl:variable name="brThreshold" select="2"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="br[count(preceding-sibling::node()[not(self::text() and normalize-space(.) = '')][position() &lt;= $brThreshold][self::br]) = $brThreshold]">
        <!-- delete this br -->
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Good one! Although it seems to require xslt 2.0!?

Comment: Looks neat. However, I was not able to apply this one. I had an error in the library I use. I use [http://www.nokogiri.org/ ] and it failed to compile the predicate. It seems it only supports XSLT 1.0 and XPath 1.0

Comment: I think it's because of the global variable `brThreshold`. If you leave it away and use `2`instead of `$brThreshold`, it should also work in xslt 1.0!